# Workaround for lacking permission when creating Python Packages

Tags: python, package

I'm writing a Python program which contains several folders and it has become big enough that making it a package makes sense (so the intra-module imports work).

The Project pretty much consists of:

```
project_folder/
 - setup.py
 - source_code/
     - somecode.py
     - __init__.py
 - inputs/
     - input_image.png
     - input_text.conf
     - __init__.py
 - outputs/
     - __init__.py
```

Now the problem I have is that when I install the package with

```
 python setup.py install
```

The package is in /usr/local/lib/... so a folder where I don't have permission to save the outputs from python without running it with elevated privileges. Not only that, but also changing the inputs is overly complicated for the average user.

So the first solution I thought of would be to have a separate folder somewhere in the /home directory where the inputs and outputs directory would be stored. However, this makes installation more difficult as the user has to go the source_code directory and change some of the paths which describe where the inputs are located.

Am I missing something obvious here, or is there no solution which is easy in every case?

Is there a way to make intra-package imports work without actually installing the package over setup.py?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--user` switch of the install command. It puts the files in `$HOME/.local` instead of `/usr/local`. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation).

You may have to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.